# Get Possible path between two nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need some help to solve a query

I have two tables like this:

```
Source       Destination
------      -------------
  1              2
  2              3
  3              4
  3              5
```

When user will input `source = 1` and `destinaton = 5` then it should populate the following things

```
1        2
2        3
3        5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand remotely what you are trying to accomplish or what you're expecting (nor the behavior you're expecting from SQL in between). Do you expect one resulting table or two? What is the reason to show all but the third row from both tables? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
WITH CTE_SD
AS
(   SELECT  [Source],[Destination] FROM SD WHERE [Destination] = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SD.[Source],SD.[Destination]
    FROM    SD
    INNER JOIN CTE_SD   ON  SD.[Destination]    =   CTE_SD.[Source]

)
SELECT * FROM CTE_SD ORDER BY [Source]
```

`... WHERE [Destination] = 5 -` Here you can use you Parameter or variable.
Also you can use your additional logic inside the CTE

Comment: I cannot figure out how to modify this code to use [Source] and [Destination] as parameters. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like a seven degrees separation problem, taken from another post answered in Stack Overflow, I would recommend you to look at the following solution:

[Degrees of Separation Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468363/degrees-of-separation-query)

Good luck!